# How break eachLayer leaflet?

Tags: javascript, foreach, leaflet

How can I exit a loop (eachLayer) in leaflet?

I tried `break` and `return` but it did not work.

Below is my code:

```
var bounds = map.getBounds();
    var notInBounds = true;
    markers.eachLayer(function(marker) {
        if (bounds.contains(marker.getLatLng())) {
            notInBounds = false;
            break;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Updated answer as of January 2017, you can `return false;` in `eachLayer` which will break out of the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I agree with the comments which say you should not break the eachLayer loop ... so this answer is purely for fun)

It is not possible without writing your own loop...

eachLayer is a very simple method: https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/master/src/layer/Layer.js#L103

```
eachLayer: function (method, context) {
        for (var i in this._layers) {
            method.call(context, this._layers[i]);
        }
        return this;
    },
```

As you see, it does not check the return value from the callback.

Instead of calling eachLayer, you should implement your own iteration (for in)
You could then handle a return value from the callback and break

Comment: Note that `_layers` is a private member, meaning it's not part of Leaflet's API and can be removed in future versions of Leaflet. Consider if breaking the loop provides a real performance improvement for you - if you don't have *lots* of layers, I think the difference is insignificant.

Answer (score 1):

*Don't*: your method with the `break` will return the same value as without the `break` and the performance difference is infinitesimally small.